# Emacs repeat string n times

Tags: string, emacs, command, repeat, editing

I'm learning the basics of navigating/editing in Emacs and I'm curious how one could accomplish the following task:

- Repeat the string 'bla ' n times in normal text editing mode.

Let's say I want to repeat it five times to generate 'bla bla bla bla bla '. I tried...

```
C-u 5 bla
```

...but the command executes after the 'b' is entered, and I only get 'bbbbb'.

I'm sure there's some basic command that can help me here...would somebody be kind enough to enlighten me :)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One way is via a [keyboard macro](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros):

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd>bla <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd>4<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>

You can also just insert the repeat count before the macro termination:

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd>bla <kbd>C-u</kbd>5<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>

Comment: Keyboard macros...awesome! Something tells me I'm going to love Emacs :).

Comment: Just for the record, the official way to use macros is `F3` to start recording and `F4` to finish and `F4` to execute. The `C-x` version is deprecated and could change.

Comment: @Malabarba That's news to me.  I can more easily touch type `C-x (`, etc.
Some flame war history here: http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/writ/emacs_keybinding.html

Answer (score 16):

You can do it with keyboard macros: <kbd>f3</kbd>`bla`<kbd>M-5 f4</kbd>.

1. <kbd>f3</kbd> means "start recording"
2. then you insert `bla`
3. <kbd>M-5</kbd> means "5 times"
4. <kbd>f4</kbd> means finish

Alternate to <kbd>M-5 f4</kbd> is just <kbd>f4</kbd>
a bunch of times.